# How to keep on submitting task to an executor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I've been searching for a solution of a situation like:
    I've a HashSet of Callables and I am submitting this Set to an executor for parallel execution.
        Now I want as soon as any submitted task is completed, I should be able to assign a new Callable to executor.

I tried this code, but with this, if I use executor.invoke then Executor waits until all tasks are completed and if I use executor.submit then tasks are completed sequentially.
 Any help would be appreciated.

```
package poc.threading;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ConcurrencyPoC_UsingExecutor_GetFreeThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        executor();
    }


    public static void executor()
    {
        try{

            ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            //create a set with all callables task
            HashSet<Callable<Object>> callables = new HashSet<>();
            callables.add(task1());
            callables.add(task2());
            callables.add(task3());
            callables.add(task4());

            //executes all task together but executor waits for completion of all tasks

            List<Future<Object>> fu = ex.invokeAll(callables);
            for(int i=0; i<fu.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(fu.get(i).get() + " , " + Thread.currentThread().getName().toString());
            }

            //executes tasks sequentially 
            for(Callable<Object> task : callables)
            {
                Future<Object> future = ex.submit(task);
                System.out.println(future.get() + " , " + Thread.currentThread().getName().toString());
            }
            ex.shutdownNow();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static Callable<Object> task1() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return new Callable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                int count = 0;
                while(count < 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("****** SLEEP TASK1 ******* "+count);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    count ++;
                }
                return "Sleep Task Of 500 Completed";
            }
        };
    }


    public static Callable<Object> task2() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return new Callable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                int count = 0;
                while(count < 6)
                {
                    System.out.println("****** SLEEP TASK2 ******* "+count);
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    count ++;
                }
                return "Sleep Task Of 300 Completed";
            }
        };
    }


    public static Callable<Object> task3() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return new Callable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                int count = 0;
                while(count < 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("****** SLEEP TASK3 ******* "+count);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    count ++;
                }
                return "Sleep Task Of 1000 Completed";
            }
        };
    }

    public static Callable<Object> task4() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return new Callable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                int count = 0;
                while(count < 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("****** SLEEP TASK4 ******* "+count);
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                    count ++;
                }
                return "Sleep Task Of 1000 Completed";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is unclear to me. If you want to notify some part of your code that a task is completed, you could use the observer pattern and add a listener to the task.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your tasks are running sequentially in the second example is because you are calling `get()` on the future before you call `submit()` on subsequent tasks.  If you do all of your `submit`s before any `get`s, then they will run in parallel.

If you're looking for tasks depending on each other, take a look at the [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class.  This type of future will allow you to begin another task once the first begins:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> task1(), ex);
CompletableFuture<Object> task2 = task1.thenApplyAsync(task1Result -> task2(), ex);
```